# AWS LambdaからSMSを送信したいがtimed outになる

Tags: flutter, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

現在、AWSのLambda（python）からSNSを利用して携帯電話へSMSを送信しようとしております。

下記の参考サイトを参考に、トピックを作成したりポリシーを作成したり下記のコードを組んだのですが、どちらのコードも実行するとtimed outになりSMSを送信することができません。

Lambdaの当該の関数の「設定」→「アクセス権限」→「（当該ロール名）」→「許可を追加」→「ポリシーをアタッチ」で「AmazonSNSFullAccess」の許可を追加しております。

また【コード２】の実行時は、IAMで新規にユーザを追加した際に表示されるアクセスキーやシークレットアクセスキーをコード中で指定してあります。

タイムアウトの時間もデフォルトの10秒から30秒に増やしてみましたが、それでも30秒後にタイムアウトになります。

コードの問題なのか、トピックやポリシー、アクセス権限の問題なのかも特定できておりません。タイムアウトせずにLambdaからSMSを送信するには、どのように修正すればよいでしょうか？何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

**参考サイト**
https://qiita.com/is_ryo/items/582656e41ffc7a8dbb5c
https://business.ntt-east.co.jp/content/cloudsolution/column-try-29.html
https://hacknote.jp/archives/42947/
など

**コード１**

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('before client.')
    sns = boto3.client('sns')

    print('before publish.')
        
    # 以下の処理でタイムアウト
    sns.publish(
        PhoneNumber='+8190XXXXXXXX', #自分の携帯電話番号
        Message='Test Message'
    )

    # timed outになりここまで処理が到達しない
    print('after publish.')
    # (以下略)
```

**コード２**

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('before client.')
    sns2 = boto3.client(
        'sns',
        aws_access_key_id='アクセスキーID',
        aws_secret_access_key='シークレットアクセスキー',
        region_name='ap-northeast-1'
    )

    print('before publish.')
        
    # 以下の処理でタイムアウト
    sns2.publish(
        PhoneNumber='+8190XXXXXXXX', #自分の携帯電話番号
        Message='Test Message'
    )

    # ここまで処理が到達しない
    print('after publish.')
    # (以下略)
```

**Function Logs**

```
START RequestId: 3edaa607-eac2-4ea1-ac85-f83968212922 Version: $LATEST
before client.
before publish.
2023-03-27T00:44:55.781Z 3edaa607-eac2-4ea1-ac85-f83968212922 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds

END RequestId: 3edaa607-eac2-4ea1-ac85-f83968212922
REPORT RequestId: 3edaa607-eac2-4ea1-ac85-f83968212922  Duration: 30032.62 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB  Init Duration: 362.01 ms
```

Comment: Lambda を VPC private サブネットで実行していませんか？
(参考 : https://blog.serverworks.co.jp/tech/2018/04/12/vpc-endpoint-sns/)

Comment: Taichi Yanagiya様　コメント誠にありがとうございます。VPC privateサブネットについてよくわかっていないので調べながら確認してみました。インターネットゲートウェイのVPC IDが、当該のLambda関数の「設定」→「VPC」に表示されているIDと一致しているので、おそらくpublicサブネットになっているのだと思います。それでも当該のLambda関数を実行するとSMSが送られずタイムアウトします。